# Net::HTTP.start works with 127.0.0.1 but not with 'localhost'. Why?

Tags: ruby

```
>>  Net::HTTP.start("127.0.0.1", 3000) { |http| http.get('/') }
=> #<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found  readbody=true>

>>  Net::HTTP.start("localhost", 3000) { |http| http.get('/') }
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Localhost is registered in /etc/hosts as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Telnet to both address works. So I think the error might be in the Net::HTTP implementation.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
```

Does anybody knows what I can do?

Comment: Is "localhost" resolving to the ipv6 address?

Comment: MWalker, you got it right! Do you want to make it as an answer so I choose it as the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the case if `localhost` is actually resolving to the IPv6 address.

Comment: Answer added based on @mwalker's comments to get a real answer to this question, but marked as community wiki so as not to take undue credit.

Comment: How do you stop localhost from resolving to the IPv6 address?